# Username and password using expect in python

Tags: python-2.7

write a piece of code that ask the user to set a password
- queries the user for his/her user name
- queries the user for his/her password twice, making sure the user enters the same password twice
- Allow Only 3 attempts to get a correct password

the rules for the password are 
- at least one number
- at least one lower cap letter
- at least one upper cap letter
- allowed characters: numbers, letters, "_", "-" and "."

The above task should be done using expect concept. Since am new to python language can anyone help me in solving this task.

```
          import pexpect
          child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
          child.expect('Name .*: ')
          child.sendline('anonymous')
          child.expect('Password:')
```

I have tried till thid and donn't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
child.sendline(raw_input('Password:'))
```

It prints `Password:` and asks the user for the password.

Comment: does this expect concept supports in windows OS? because it shows error in the first line itself

Comment: input is supported. Sorry, I was using Python 3. Edited it.